# Trying to Update one table with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **Ledger Table** with the following three columns along with others not included for brevity:

```
**gl_account id** | **gl_amount** |  **GL_adjustmentAmount**
    9500          |     NULL      |        NULL
     ...          |   ...         |        ...
```

I have a different **Adjustment Table** with differing Columns from above except for two:

```
**gl_account id** |   **GL_adjustmentamount**
     9500         |           289.84
     9500         |           9.63
     9500         |           13646.11
     9500         |           835.31
     9500         |           -210
     9500         |           -1019.02
     9500         |           -200
```

I need to update the **Ledger Table** to include all 7 new gl_adjustments but it only includes one of the values which is 289.84.

Here is my code.

```
UPDATE LedgerTable
SET [GL_adjustmentamount] = adjust.GL_adjustmentamount 
FROM LedgerTable AS genLed
     FULL OUTER JOIN AdjustmentTable AS adjust
     ON genLed.gl_accountid = adjust.gl_accountid
```

Comment: What are your expected results?  Are you trying to `sum` the values?

Comment: Do you want one record with the total of all adjustments in the Ledger table? If so, you want to aggregate in a cte/subquery then update, otherwise if you want one record per adjustment, you need to `INSERT` rather than`UPDATE`.

Comment: I'm using sql 2008. I wanted to initially have every GL_adjustedamount in the Ledger but I think having the sum value would be BEST. :)

Answer (score 1):

**CASE 1 : Update only for one account**

You can use this if you want this for only one account :

```
declare @AccountID INT
set @AccountID = 9500

update  Ledger
set     GL_adjustmentAmount = GL_adjustmentAmount + (select     SUM(a.GL_AdjustmentAmount)
                                                     from       Adjustment a
                                                     where      a.GL_AccountID = @AccountID)
where   GL_AccountID = @AccountID
```

Mind you, the `accountId` will have to be specified here.

**CASE 2 : Update for all accounts**

If you want this to work for all accounts (*which should & will more likely be the case*), then you will need a more "generalized" query something of the sort :

```
update Ledger
set     GL_AdjustmentAmount = ISNULL(GL_AdjustmentAmount,0) + ISNULL(collatedAdjustments.adjustment, 0)
from Ledger ledger
inner join 
(select         a.GL_AccountID,
                SUM(a.GL_AdjustmentAmount) as Adjustment
from            Adjustment adjustments
group by        adjustments.GL_accountID) as collated
on              ledger.GL_accountID = collated.GL_accountID
```

Here's some some sample data you can test this against :

```
CREATE TABLE Ledger(GL_AccountID int, GL_Amount int, GL_AdjustmentAmount int);
CREATE TABLE Adjustment(GL_AccountID int, GL_AdjustmentAmount int);

INSERT INTO Ledger(GL_AccountID,GL_Amount, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, null, null);
INSERT INTO Ledger(GL_AccountID,GL_Amount, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, null, null);
INSERT INTO Ledger(GL_AccountID,GL_Amount, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9700, null, null);
INSERT INTO Ledger(GL_AccountID,GL_Amount, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9800, null, null);

INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, 289.84);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, 9.63);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, 13646.11);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, 835.31);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, -210);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, -1019.02);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9500, -200);

INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, 29.84);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, 29.63);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, 16646.11);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, 335.31);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, -1210);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, -2019.02);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9600, -1200);

INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9700, 2239.02);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9700, 1400);

INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9800, 4121.02);
INSERT INTO Adjustment(GL_AccountID, GL_AdjustmentAmount) VALUES(9800, 1234);
```

This query takes any previous adjustments (in the `ledger` table) into the equation as well.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Something tells me the OP isn't passing in an Account Id.

Comment: Maybe you want to include `Ledger.GL_AdjustmentAmount` as well rather than just replacing it?  i.e. `set GL_AdjustmentAmount = GL_AdjustmentAmount + ...`

Comment: @sgeddes I've updated my answer to include both cases. If I've understood your point correctly, then you're right - Passing an individual `Account id` shouldn't be the case as when you're updating the ledger, you'd want to update for all accounts rather than one.

Comment: Thanks this helped!

Comment: @Ace If this answer helped you, then you mark this as the answer so that it will help anyone else who stumbles across this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * into LedgerTable
from Adjustment Table
```